# Upload to HDFS stops with warning "Slow ReadProcessor read"

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

When I try to upload files that are about 20 GB into HDFS they usually upload till about 12-14 GB then they stop uploading and I get a bunch of these warnings through command line

```
    "INFO hdfs.DataStreamer: Slow ReadProcessor read fields for block BP-222805046-10.66.4.100-1587360338928:blk_1073743783_2960 took 62414ms (threshold=30000ms); ack: seqno: 226662 reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 0 flag: 0, targets:"
```

However, if I try to upload the files like 5-6 times, they sometimes work after the 4th or 5th attempt. I believe if I alter some data node storage settings I can achieve consistent uploads without issues but I don't know what parameters to modify in the hadoop configurations. Thanks!

Edit: This happens when I put the file into HDFS through python program which uses a subprocess call to put the file in. However, even if I directly call it from command line I still run into the same issue.